# Is there an HTTP reverse proxy for IIS smooth streaming that can terminate SSL, but retrieve media using HTTP

Tags: iis, ssl, reverse-proxy

Here is what I am trying to do.

User <--(https)--> Server1 <--(http)--> IIS Smooth Streaming Server (Server2)

- User requests IIS smooth streaming media from Server1 using HTTPS.  The URL and certificate, etc. are all valid and present on Server1
- Server1 then makes a request using the same URL (but replacing the destination IP/host) using HTTP to Server2
- Server2 responds with data over HTTP
- Server1 transmits data over HTTPS back to User

So, all smooth streaming media on Server2 has aliases on Server1.

My questions are:

1. Can one do this easily using Apache mod_rewrite on Server1?  Are there any examples that you are familiar with.  I've searched a lot, but haven't seen any examples that solve the specific problem above
2. IIS 7.0 has url rewrite functionality too, so Server1 could be IIS as well.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this using IIS?

It seems like one can write some software that can take any of these requests, do another request to the back-end server, retrieve the data and serve it out again, but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel if I didn't have to.

Thanks,

Martin Jaite

Answer (score 0):

ISA server can do that. Not sure if Application Request Routing in IIS7 can handle the SSL requirement..

Comment: I did some more digging around using "Applicaiton Request Routing" and "SSL" and found this:
http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/10/ssl-off-loading-in-application-request-routing.aspx

It seems like this might work.  Will report back after testing.